# problema con expresión regular, función test javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo esta expresión regular `let e = /[a-z]+/gi` para capturar palabras dentro del siguiente texto:

TOTAL SUBTOTAL DEMAS DEMAS OTRO OTRO 1819.00 1,647.20 4,681.76 5,000.00 990.00 5,436.57 750.00 568.50 565.50 565.50 510.00 1,568.10 1,420.00 4,036.00 4,310.34, 853.45 4,686.70 646.55 491.95 489.37 489.37 439.66

Se supone que debería de identificar las letras y cuando las encuentra devolver true, incluso lo ratifique en la pagina de https://regexr.com.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no funciono, de hecho tiene un comportamiento extraño después de aceptar las dos primeras palabras como true acepta las demás de par en par:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
let bandera = [,0];

let e = /[a-z]+/gi

    calcular.forEach((value, index)=>{
        bandera[0] = e.test(value)
        console.log(value)
        console.log(bandera[0])
        if(bandera[0] === true){
            bandera[1] += 1;
        }
    })
```

Bandera es un Array para no crear dos variables, en `bandera[0]` obtengo el true o false de la expresión regular y en `bandera[1]` solo guardo un incremento si encontró una coincidencia.

Ya se que si la expresión regular tiene un **i** es *case insensitive* solo puse [a-zA-z] por lo frustrante y extraño del caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Del la Referencia de JS:

> multiples llamadas a test() sobre la misma instancia global de una expresión regular avanzará desde de la ocurrencia anterior

Es decir, al repetirse la palabra en `value`, es como si le pidieras buscar la misma expresión después de la última coincidencia, la cual no existe y por lo tanto la segunda vez es false.

La solución, es quitar la bandera global `g`:

```
let e = /[a-z]+/i
```

dado que no estas comparando una cadena con varias palabras, sino palabra por palabra de un arreglo.

Comment: [Mas info aquí](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexpbuiltinexec) (_punto 4 y 12_) y [aca también](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#using_test_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag)

Comment: Funciono, tienes mi agradecimiento.